# Rails SECRET_KEY_BASE returns nil on local production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that I want to run on production both on cloud and local. This is to make it possible to work on it offline. 
To do so I'm synchronizing the local database with the database on the cloud. Which are then identical.

Then of course I will install the app on local computer and cloud.

So far I have developed my computer for development and on heroku for production and everything works fine.

On the production computer I installed rubystack and ran the app on it and it works fine as long as I'm on development.

But if I switch to production it can't find the secret key. Although I have on my secrets file:

```
production
secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

And anyway it works on heroku on production.

A recap of the steps:

- Created my app on my computer with ubuntu os
- Set it up on heroku and it works fine
- Installed rubystack on production computer with windows os, copied the app and database and ran migrations.

If on production computer i check on console for production SECRET_KEY_BASE it returns nil.

But on heroku it works fine.

What am I missing? Can it be caused by different ruby configuration on my ubuntu computer and Ruby Stack?

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/YOUR_APP_NAME/settings, click on `Reveal Config Vars` and compy the value behind `SECRET_KEY_BASE`.

Then start your local Server with `SECRET_KEY_BASE=COPIED_VALUE rails s -e production`.

Or you can place `export SECRET_KEY_BASE=COPIED_VALUE` in your `.bashrc` (depends on your used shell) file.

Comment: If I start the server as you suggested I get: `'SECRET_KEY_BASE' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. And I can't find the .bashrc file, so I created it on home directory and added your code but that doesn't fix it..

Comment: i'm using rbenv

Comment: Ok as I'm on windows I need to put SECRET... at the end. But that doesn't work too. I got it working now by setting it explicitly on secrets file. I know it's not a good solution but it's the only one I can get to work.